# Are nested array node types valid in Jackrabbit JCR?

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I'm fairly new to the JCR space and have inherited a project using Jackrabbit/Apache Oak as the JCR implementation.

I have a data model which I'm trying to translate into a JCR node structure like below:

```
{
    "someProperty": [
        [ "some-property-1", "some-property-2" ],
        [ "some-property-3", "some-property-4" ]
    ]
}
```

Is this possible?

The reason I ask, is that it seems like all methods for adding nodes on the `javax.jcr.Node` type take a name.

For instance:

```java
addNode(String relPath)
```

I'm guessing it'd be best to model out the subarrays (e.g. `[ "some-property-1", "some-property-2" ]`) as their own nodes, but not sure if this is possible with the facilities at hand.

Please excuse any ignorance of JCR!

In an ideal world, I'd do something like:

```java
parentNode.addNode("someProperty")
    .addNode().setProperty(["some-property-1", "some-property-2"])
    .addNode().setProperty(["some-property-3", "some-property-4"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no nesting like that in JCR.

You could:

- transform these into nestable nodes, or
- overload the property name, or
- just use string values, and parse/serialize yourself...